# Unable to call a button for asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

So the problem here is that i am unable to call a button that another developer created and handed over the site to me.
He is not available and I am not very much into ASP.net but really need to figure this out.
The code is:

```
<div class="clearfix">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel2">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text=""/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnMore" runat="server" Text="more"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>                                                    
</div>
```

The btnMore should call a button at server making the word more to be a link that will expand the div to get a blog post from the database.
It is not doing so.
Any idea why??

Comment: You have tagged this as `asp.net-mvc` (multiple versions) but based on your code, you're doing ASP.NET Web Forms. Are you using a combination of the two, or is this just mis-tagged?

Answer (score 0):

Your LinkButton has no associated action with it. You need to set the OnClick attribute to the function on the server side that has the correct signature. For example...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnMore" runat="server" Text="more" OnClick="btnMore_Click" />
```

Then in your code behind...

```
protected void btnMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //do your server side stuff
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It gave me quite the kickstart. There is only one little problem as i mentioned, I am unable to find the source where the file is stored as it was developed by another person and he is out of the equation. Could you help me on grounds stating under what directory will it be stored ideally as it is a huge website and i have no idea about asp.net file structure.

Comment: Well, .aspx pages contain the HTML markup, usually the corresponding code behind file is .aspx.cs or .aspx.vb depending on your language. The rest of the filename is the same. You can confirm by looking at the Page directive at the top of the .aspx pages. Site-wide code usually goes in a folder called App_Code. For more info, check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx)